# How do I use a variable instead of a literal string?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function:

```
Private Function generateXMLSchema(ZRouteName) As String

    Dim generatedXmlSchema As String ="<Name>tEST 250504</Name>"
```

Where the value of the "Name" element is a literal string.

I want to use the variable `ZRouteName` instead of the literal string:

```
"<Name>"ZRouteName"</Name>"
```

I am getting the error: "Syntax Error".

Please help to rectify this.

Comment: I made some extensive improvements to the grammar of your question - if you disagree with them please feel free to roll back my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the ampersand (&) to concatenate your variable to the string like this

`"<Name>" & ZRouteName & "</Name>"`